# save() generating new entry instead updating Django

Tags: python, django

I am not understanding why, but an instance always get created copying the one I am trying to edit. Also, as I can see FormSet I am using does not have an "instance" parameter to be added to its constructor. Anyways, the problem is that an instance of both Offer and OfferItem gets generated when I am editing an object.

```
def manage_offer(request, number=None):
    param_offer = Offer.objects.filter(id=number).first()
    param_items = OfferItem.objects.filter(offer=param_offer).values()

if request.method == 'POST':
    offer_form = OfferForm(request.POST, instance=param_offer)
    item_formset = OfferItemFormSet(request.POST, initial=param_items)

    if offer_form.is_valid() and item_formset.is_valid():

        # User selected go back and correct something
        if request.POST.get('back', False):

            return render(request,
                          'offer_edit.html',
                              {
                                  'forms': offer_form,
                                  'formset': item_formset,
                                  'offer_edit': True,
                              })

        # Proceeds with either saving or submitting request

        offer = offer_form.save(commit=False)
        offer.tax = offer_form.cleaned_data['tax'].value

        #Sotres items to be sent back to commit part
        offer_items = []
        #Gets the items from the form and stores them to conf. page
        for item_in_formset in item_formset.forms:
            item = item_in_formset.save(commit=False)
            item.item_code = get_item_code(item_in_formset.cleaned_data['name'])
            item.type = get_item_type(item_in_formset.cleaned_data['name'])
            offer.update_total(item.calc_total())
            # Adds items into list for invoice_ready page
            offer_items.append(item)

        # Request goes to confirmation page
        if request.POST.get('proceed', False):

            return render(request,
                          'offer_edit.html',
                              {
                                  'offer_form': offer_form,
                                  'item_formset': item_formset,
                                  'offer_ready': True,
                                  'offer': offer,
                                  'items': offer_items,
                              })
        # Passes confirmation page and saves offer
        offer.save()
        # Makes sure the value is correct by recalculating
        offer.reset_total()

        for obj_item in offer_items:
            obj_item.offer = offer
            offer.update_total(obj_item.calc_total())
            #commits to DB
            offer.save()
            obj_item.save()

        return render(request,
                      'offer_edit.html',
                          {
                              'success_add_offer': True,
                              'offer': offer,
                          },
                     )

# GET generates a blank or instanced page
else:
    offer_form = OfferForm(initial=
                               {'company': Company.objects.filter(is_default=True).first(),
                                'tax': Tax.objects.filter(is_default=True).first()
                                }, instance=param_offer)
    item_formset = OfferItemFormSet(initial=param_items)

return render(request, 'offer_edit.html',
              {
                  'forms': offer_form,
                  'formset': item_formset,
                  'edit_offer': number,
              })
```

## Forms.py

```
class OfferItemForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = OfferItem
    # Some widgets and stuff ...

class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False

OfferItemFormSet = formset_factory(OfferItemForm, formset=RequiredFormSet)
```

Comment: Does your `manage_offer` function intend to return some stuff? Why have you set `number` parameter equal to None?

Comment: Because if no number is provided it will create a new entry instead of editing one. I have manually set None to 1 or 2 for debugging purposes, depending on my entries and still I get the same problem.

Comment: Have you checked if the form actually gets this `param_offer` as an instance?

Comment: It does and that's why it is so weird. I am able to handle the instance editing and adding new Items, the problem happens when I submit the page. Instead of changing the one in place it creates a new one. I have other views that edit existing entries and they worked just fine - with the exception that they are not as complex as this one. It is just a simple ModelForm.

Comment: Is 'Initial' the instancing parameter for FormSets like 'Instance' is to ModelForms? I am getting the FormSet properly fulfilled but this could be the reason why it is saving a new instance instead of editing it. I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem: since I am using the same View function to either edit or add a new entry, on my template form I must make sure I am also identifying if I am editing or not, because the function takes a parameter in case I am editing. In that case I must change the URL in the Post form.

Just a silly mistake take took me a few hours to find out.